# How to put gpaste with the "right box" of dash-to-panel?

Tags: icons, 22.04, gnome-shell-extension, top-bar, clipboard-manager

Before I formatted my pc, I had the gpaste installed on my ubuntu and it was displaying normally on the dash-to-panel.

After resistalling ubuntu I installed gpaste, I can open it as a standalone application, but it no longer shows on the dash to panel:

This is the right side of the dash-to-panel, it used to appear beside the "en" icon, how can I get it back there?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should install the extension: "gnome-shell-extension-gpaste" .
Then, if the icon doesn't appear on the dash after a reboot, You should enable the extension using the "gnome-shell-extension-manager".  May be you should install it.
For me that works.
Wishes